# change page size for print based on class of the certain element in css

Tags: html, css

I work on a single page application. I want to print page with landscape or portrait orientation based on `class` of the `div`. And the hardest part: I want to use only css, no javascript.

For example,
I have a default size of the print

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape
  }
}
```

but I want to resize it if block `"frame"` has a modificator `"media"`

Unfortunately, that's doesn't work:

```
@media print {
  @page .frame ._media {
    size: portrait
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add selector with `@page` as you have mentioned. There are only some psuedo classes that can be added. You can read more about them here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page

The best solution will be to use JS. But since you want to do it only with CSS.

There is no way you can set the `@page` rule using the classes.

My solution would be to:
Have two different stylesheets(say style1.css, style2.css) and on the pages where you have class1 include style1.css and on the pages where you have class2 include style2.css.

**style1.css:**

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape
  }
}
```

**and style2.css:**

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: portrait;
  }
}
```

That's the only way you can set two different @page rules.

Otherwise please use Javascript.